# Can't get Plus (+) Button in Safari Mobile with meta tags

Tags: iphone, html, mobile-safari, meta

Ok, this seems like it should be so simple.

I have a web app:

http://cloudmusiccompany.appspot.com/

It has the META tag:

<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

I know that it only goes full screen when the user clicks the "+" at the bottom of the screen, and then launches the short cut.

But I've never been able to get it to show me the "+" button. I see the other, share button.

As you can see from the source, I have a splash screen and an icon.

I've tried putting the meta and link tags in different orders. Nothing seems to give me the "+" button.

Comment: Just found something that said the "+" was replaced in iOS 4.2 with the button I see. But it still doesn't use my icon or splash screen when it saves. And on iPhone 5 the screen is truncated leaving about the same amount of space! That's a different question, probably. But why aren't isn't my icon being used when it's added to the homescreen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct that `plus` button was replaced in iOS 4.2 with the `share` button.

---

To set the home screen icon, use this meta tag:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="icon.png"/>
```

Or, this one if you want gloss added to the icon:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icon.png"/>
```

To set the splash screen, use:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash.png" />
```

Comment: Sure, and the page I am making (see link ikn op) has that. I think. But it doesn't show my icon (it shows a thumbnail of the page itself).

Comment: @mikethematrix, Your page uses `link ref="apple-touch-icon"` as opposed to `link rel="apple-touch-icon"` (note `ref`/`rel`). When I changed that in a remote debug session, the issue was fixed and the site displayed the correct icon, as shown [here](http://imgur.com/vwjlcId.jpg).